# MariaDB constraint is incorrectly formed although columns are of the same type

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3, flyway

I've got a problem while creating (altering) foreign key.

I have two tables in my DB (created via flyway migrations):

**connector (migration)**

```sql
create table if not exists connector
(
    id char(36) not null,
    # other fields omitted
    primary key (id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
  COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';
```

**connector_preset (migration)**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS connector_preset
(
    id CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    # other fields omitted

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I want to create a link between **connector** and **connector_preset**, so I created another migration like this:

```sql
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `connector`
    # `connector_preset`.`id`
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `preset_id` CHAR(36),
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_connector_preset_id` FOREIGN KEY (`preset_id`) REFERENCES `connector_preset` (`id`);
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
SQL State  : HY000
Error Code : 1005
Message    : (conn=4) Can't create table `test`.`connector` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
Location   : db/migration/...
Line       : 34
Statement  : ALTER IGNORE TABLE `connector`
    # `connector_preset`.`id`
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `preset_id` CHAR(36),
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_connector_preset_id` FOREIGN KEY (`preset_id`) REFERENCES `connector_preset` (`id`),
```

The columns seem to be of the same type. Also, for some reason it works in local k8s cluster (10.3.29-MariaDB), but fails in integration tests (testcontainers, MariaDB 10.6.11). Also fails in GH Actions which use 10.3.29, which is strange since it's working locally.

If I set mariadb version in testcontainers to 10.3.29 - it still fails.

Tried altering **connector_preset** table to use the same charset and collation:

```sql
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `connector_preset` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';
```

Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the missing

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
```

in the `connector_preset` table.

Check [this working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/13x_P5HD)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS connector_preset
(
    id CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    # other fields omitted

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'   --- added
  COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'; --- added
```

Comment: Is there a way to not modify connector_preset create statement? We use migrations, I can't directly modify the create statement

Comment: Something like ```ALTER IGNORE TABLE `connector_preset` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';``` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @SebastianLore `ALTER TABLE connector_preset CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';` https://dbfiddle.uk/h6BtOjHO

Comment: Thanks a lot..!